# How to correctly forward structured binding arguments in a macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, structured-bindings

I would like to write a macro that can take an arbitrary number of variable bindings, followed by a single expression, and rewrite those as a lambda function. The goal is to see if it's possible to implement something like the [concise lambda syntax proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0573r2.html) using current language features, or if this has to be handled by the compiler.

The challenge here is that macros don't support `,` inside arguments, and structured bindings are not allowed to be wrapped in `()`, the easiest workaround for this issue (at least in clang). The other common workaround is to define a `COMMA` macro, but since I'm trying to play with a more concise lambda syntax, this is not an option.

I managed to implement this for single argument functions by using `__VA_ARGS__` and concatenating everything except the last argument:

- `FN(x, x == 0)` results in `[&](auto&& __arg) { auto& x = __arg; return x == 0; }`
- `FN([x, y], x == y)` results in `[&](auto&& __arg) { auto& [x, y] = __arg; return x == y; }`

You can see the full implementation on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1go2Wg).

However, I'm stuck trying to implementing the general n-argument for `FN([x, y], c, [f, g, h], f*x - y + c / h * g)`

which should result in

```
[&](auto&& __arg1, auto&& __arg2, auto&& __arg3) { 
  auto& [x, y] = __arg1; 
  auto& c = __arg2;
  auto& [f, g, h] = __arg3;
  return f*x - y + c / h * g; 
}
```

Are there any good techniques to group the arguments by matching opening `[` and closing `]`, if any? Or maybe there's a better approach to writing this macro that I haven't thought of?

Comment: to clarify, I don't see the proposal make any kind of accommodations for structured bindings... is this just something you're trying to attempt yourself?

Comment: *"structured bindings are not allowed to be wrapped in `()`"* How about this: `#define I(...) __VA_ARGS__` `#define FOO(a,b) auto &[I a] = b;` (then `FOO((x,y),z)` expands to `auto &[x,y] = z;`)

Comment: I suggest looking into [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maybe there's a better approach

Shooting for this.

> structured bindings are not allowed to be wrapped in `()`

...

> Are there any good techniques to group the arguments by matching opening `[` and closing `]`, if any?

There are two truths here: (1) the preprocessor will match `()`'s, and only matches `()`'s (no other grouping operators). (2) structured bindings cannot be wrapped with parentheses.  (1) means you don't want to use `[`/`]` in your macro; you want to use `()`'s.  (2) doesn't really conflict; all it means is you want to leave translation phase 4 with `[]`'s, not `()`'s.  FYI, I'll use the term *tuple* to refer to a parentheses matched, comma delimited token list (consistent with boost preprocessor's terminology).

So let's entertain the idea that tuple arguments are structure bindings, and identifiers are ordinary variable bindings.  From a form perspective, we just need a macro that takes `(a,b)` to `[a,b]` and `c` to `c`.  This is a job for pattern matching.

**Part 1: to square a tuple**

Here I'll use an indirect `THIRD` macro, that just expands to its third argument, just indirectly.  The indirect part is the sneaky bit; that lets us construct a throwaway first parameter that would normally just get ignored.  But if that first parameter invokes a macro, the expansion can have a comma, which would shift the second argument into third place just prior to picking the third argument.  Detecting if an argument `A` is a parenthetical is easy; just preface it with a function-like macro name; if it's parenthetical that's an invocation... if not, it's just two tokens.  Here's how to exploit that to make our macro:

```
#define M_THIRD(...) M_THIRD_(__VA_ARGS__,,,)
#define M_THIRD_(A,B,C,...) C
#define M_SQUARETUPLE(X) M_THIRD(M_PARDETECT X, M_SQUARE, ) X
#define M_PARDETECT(...) ,
#define M_SQUARE(...) [__VA_ARGS__]
```

**Part 2: Counting, delimitable iterator**

To me it's more natural to iterate through a tuple than through "everything but the last argument".  So let's imagine we're targeting your example case, and at some step in the processing we have `M_LAMBDIZE_PAIR( ((x,y),c,(f,g,h)), f*x - y + c / h * g)`.  We want to be able to iterate that first tuple, but while iterating it we want to have a number corresponding to the ordinal position of each element (so we can build things like `__arg1`), and we want to be able to use a delimiter that may have commas in it (so we can generate `auto&& __arg1, auto&& __arg2, auto&& __arg3`).  So let's build an iterator and plan for these features specifically.  Tuples are great ways to generically wrap delimiters that might have commas, since again the preprocessor matches parentheses.

So here's a generic iteration construct that fits the bill:

```
#define M_INC(X) M_CONC(M_INC_,X)
#define M_INC_1 2
#define M_INC_2 3
#define M_INC_3 4
#define M_INC_4 5
#define M_INC_5 6
#define M_INC_6 7
#define M_INC_7 8
#define M_INC_8 9
#define M_INC_9 10

#define M_UNWRAP(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define M_TOEACH(M,L,...) M_CONC(M_TOEACH_,M_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(M,L,1,__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_TOEACH_1(M,L,I,A)      M(I,A)
#define M_TOEACH_2(M,L,I,A,...)  M(I,A) M_UNWRAP L M_TOEACH_1(M,L,M_INC(I),__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_TOEACH_3(M,L,I,A,...)  M(I,A) M_UNWRAP L M_TOEACH_2(M,L,M_INC(I),__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_TOEACH_4(M,L,I,A,...)  M(I,A) M_UNWRAP L M_TOEACH_3(M,L,M_INC(I),__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_TOEACH_5(M,L,I,A,...)  M(I,A) M_UNWRAP L M_TOEACH_4(M,L,M_INC(I),__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_TOEACH_6(M,L,I,A,...)  M(I,A) M_UNWRAP L M_TOEACH_5(M,L,M_INC(I),__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_TOEACH_7(M,L,I,A,...)  M(I,A) M_UNWRAP L M_TOEACH_6(M,L,M_INC(I),__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_TOEACH_8(M,L,I,A,...)  M(I,A) M_UNWRAP L M_TOEACH_7(M,L,M_INC(I),__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_TOEACH_9(M,L,I,A,...)  M(I,A) M_UNWRAP L M_TOEACH_8(M,L,M_INC(I),__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_TOEACH_10(M,L,I,A,...) M(I,A) M_UNWRAP L M_TOEACH_9(M,L,M_INC(I),__VA_ARGS__)
```

`M_TOEACH` takes a macro `M`, a parentheses-wrapped delimiter `L`, and a list of arguments to iterate.  For each argument it calls `M(I,A)` where `I` is the ordinal for the argument and `A` is the argument itself.  `M_UNWRAP` is always applied to the delimiter; so we can pass `(,)` in to comma delimit, or just `()` in to omit the delimiter with the same construct.

A helper indirect call macro:

```
#define M_CALL(...) M_CALL_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_CALL_(M,...) M(__VA_ARGS__)
```

...takes a function like macro name as the first argument and its arguments as the following, and performs an indirect call.  This is useful if we want to unwrap a tuple to iterate through it, but have that unwrapping fully apply by the time we make the actual call.  Using that, here's an example `M_LAMBDIZE_PAIR`:

```
#define M_PRDECL(I,A) auto&& M_CONC(__arg,I)
#define M_ARDECL(I,A) auto& M_SQUARETUPLE(A) = M_CONC(__arg,I);
#define M_LAMBDIZE_PAIR(ARGS, EXPR) \
   [&]( M_CALL(M_TOEACH,M_PRDECL,(,),M_UNWRAP ARGS)) { \
      M_CALL(M_TOEACH,M_ARDECL,(),M_UNWRAP ARGS) \
      return EXPR; \
}
```

More complete example: https://godbolt.org/z/xTh1WI